# Appending large arrays in .h5 consumes large time and space

Tags: numpy, dataset, h5py, pytables, hdf

I wanted to create a file containing a huge array of size (50000,1998,101).

```
count = 0
X_data = []
Y_data = []
X_file = tables.open_file('train_X.h5', mode='w')
Y_file = tables.open_file('train_Y.h5', mode='w')
x_atom = tables.Float64Atom()
y_atom = tables.Float64Atom()
x_ds = X_file.create_earray(X_file.root, 'X_array', x_atom,(0,1998,101))
y_ds = Y_file.create_earray(Y_file.root, 'Y_array', y_atom,(0,497,1))
print(x_ds.shape)
for i in range(50000):
    print("iter",i)
    b =  np.random.randint(53)
    x, y =  create_training_example(background_new[b], elitas, negatives,i) 
    x = np.swapaxes(x,0,1) #shape (1998, 101)
    y = np.swapaxes(y,0,1) #shape (497, 1)
    x=np.expand_dims(x,0)
    y=np.expand_dims(y,0)
    x_ds.append(x)
    y_ds.append(y)
X_file.close()
Y_file.close()
print("Finished")
```

The above code is taking huge time at iteration 2000 itself and it get killed there.The h5 file with 600 arrays is about 1.2 GB.Why is it taking that large space and time.Is there any way to create large dataset for such large array by appending arrays ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Jennings, you are already appending the `x` and `y` arrays to the `x_ds` and `y_ds` EArrays. So, that's not really the solution to your problem. I can't run your code without your function `create_training_example`. However, I used it to create a simple example that uses the same method to create `train_x.h5` (only) and populate with arrays created with `np.arange().reshape()`. I created 2,000 arrays of shape (1998,101). This sould be a good proxy for the behavior you see. The code runs "reasonably fast" on my laptop (w/ 24 GB RAM), and creates a `train_X.h5` file that is 3.9 GB. Based on your post, that seems appropriate (600 arrays ~= 1.2GB). Obviously you will get a far larger file if you create 50,000 arrays (maybe ~100 GB?)

You might have a hardware resource problem. I suggest you run my example to see how it behaves. Once you have that data point, you can decide what to investigate next. Some ideas:

1. Create `train_X.h5` and `train_Y.h5` separately.
2. Populate Earray datasets with 500 arrays at a time (modify code to
   open training files in append mode)

**Code below (modified 1/2/2019): increased range() and added output of RAM and timing stats:**

```
import numpy as np
import tables
import time
X_file = tables.open_file('train_X.h5', mode='w')
x_atom = tables.Float64Atom()
x_ds = X_file.create_earray(X_file.root, 'X_array', x_atom,(0,1998,101))
print(x_ds.shape)
start = time.clock()
for i in range(20000):
    x = np.arange(1998*101).reshape(1998, 101)
    x=np.expand_dims(x,0)
    x_ds.append(x)
    if ( ((i+1) % 100) == 0 ) :
        print('iter=',i,'DS Mem Size  = ', x_ds.size_in_memory, 'Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start))

print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) )
X_file.close()
print("Finished")
```

Comment: I tried the code in ubuntu system 32 GB RAM and it becomes slow and gets killed after 13K arrays are stored.Anyother approach

Comment: @Jennings, sorry to hear that. I modified my code to increase range(20000) and added output to get memory usage and timing stats, then reran to get the stats. On my laptop w/ 24 GB RAM, it takes 536 seconds (~9 minutes) to create the HDF5 file with 20,000 arrays in x_ds . I will update code in my answer to reflect changes.

Comment: Did you notice in my code I have to store values from both x and y values at the same time...

Comment: @Jennings, yes I noticed. :-) When I run into performance bottlenecks, I start simple and add complexity until I find the source. I suggest you start by determining if you can create 50000 `x_ds` datasets. You don't HAVE to store x and y at the same time. If you are memory constrained, you might have to run once to create `train_X.h5`, then run again to create `train_Y.h5`.

Comment: In 15 minutes it generates 5k records only..I just used x_ds alone and am using 32Gb RAM.Is hardware resource the issue ?? SHould I need more RAM ?

Comment: I don't think you have a memory problem. In fact, if there are memory constraints, I should see them before you. Clearly we are getting different behavior. I can create 20k x_ds datasets in 9 minutes (w/ 24 GB RAM). Pytables says the 20k x_ds dataset RAM requirement is 30GB. If RAM is a constraint, I should see it. I plotted my performance stats and will post the image in an answer below. I am out of ideas -- I'ma Pytables user, but not a performance guru.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186081/discussion-between-jennings-and-kcw78).

Answer (score 0):

The image below is a plot of the dataset Memory (blue) used (as reported by Pytables) and elapsed Time (red) for the example I posted above. It shows bilinear behavior creating/writing up to 20,000 datasets (EArrays). Notice the 'kink" once DS mem size exceeds 2.5GB.
Note: My first set of stats were from a run on a local drive with MS OneDrive backup. That appears to be the cause of the irregular bumps and wiggles (not Pytables chunking). I reran on a different drive, and got smoother behavior. Both were run on Windows-7 w/ 24 GB RAM.
**Image below shows stats from 2nd run.** 
[image]

**Image below shows stats from 1st  run.** The little wiggles/bumps in the timing data are not due to Pytables chunking. Large dataset write performance is about 15% slower with MS OneDrive backup.

[image]